# JavaScript Replace comma between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

hi I am having difficulty creating a regex expression to replace Comma (,) between two characters my string look like this.

```
let str=Amazon,buy,0123,4213,5424
```

I want

```
Amazon buy,0123,4213,5424
```

I try

```
str.replace(/\D(,)\D/," ")
```

but that removes two characters as well

```
    Amazo uy,0123,4213,5424
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few answers here that work well, here's another idea depending on the variability of your string:

[image]

What is going on here is:

1. First get everything up until the first equals sign.
2. Now capture everything until the first comma ("Amazon").
3. Now grab everything (buy,01234,4213,5424).

Depending on the complexity of your inputs (spaces, escapes, etc.) this would only go so far but to me it seems like it could work for your situation.

View at: https://regex101.com/r/6wYdUg/1

And another option using a lookbehind with two named capturing groups:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this really is all you want to do, then a regular expression may be overkill. Here's two approaches:

```js
let str="Amazon,buy,0123,4213,5424";
let newStr = str.replace(",", " ");
console.log(newStr);
```

```js
let str="Amazon,buy,0123,4213,5424";
let newStr = str.replace("Amazon,", "Amazon ");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: this was just an example of one line of csv, and they are not all same

Comment: @Lutif Is it always the first comma that you need removed? If so, my first example will work.

Comment: Scott -- probably the best answer here!